# css reset for the html5 button tag

Tags: css, html

What lines of code should one use to reset the html5 button tag to act alike in all browsers? Currently IE9 goes bananas when trying to syle the button tag.

display:block; is known, but what else..

Answer (score 3):

Even if it may not answer your question directly its at least a working solution: You could use an ***anchor tag*** and style it the same way as you would the *button tag*.

I wouldn't recommend the usage of *conditional comments* or other *css hacks*.